# do you think the 2015 hp pavillion 14 ab166us has hdmi 1.4 or 2.0

Tags: hp-pavilion

do you think that the hp pavillion 14-ab166us has hdmi 1.4 or 2.0

Comment: What did your research tell you?

Answer (score 1):

So you may have tried to look at the specs for this model, and ran into [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04764665).

And you probably scrolled down and found this:

[image]

This is the official specs from HP, saying "1 HDMI" in the list of "External Ports."  But nothing stating what HDMI version.  Not too helpful, right?

However, the key lies here, if we scroll up and look at "Video Graphics" - which is the component that generates the display and is connected to the HDMI port internally.

[image]

So this system has an "Intel HD graphics 5500" chipset for video.

Searching on this took me [here](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-5500.125586.0.html), and sadly it seems the Intel HD Graphics 5500 only goes up to HDMI 1.4.  Below is an excerpt with the relevant information.

> The HD Graphics 5500 represents the mid-range version of the Broadwell
> GPU family and consists of one slice with 24 EUs. Beyond that, there
> is also a low-end variant (GT1, 12 EUs) as well as higher-end models
> (GT3/GT3e + eDRAM, 48 EUs).
>
> All Broadwell GPUs support OpenCL 2.0 and DirectX 12 (FL 11_1). The
> video engine can now decode H.265 using both fixed function hardware
> as well as available GPU shaders. Up to three displays can be
> connected via DP 1.2/eDP 1.3 (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz) or HDMI 1.4a
> (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 24 Hz). HDMI 2.0, however, is not supported.